# How to store previous element in a for loop in a python

Tags: python

I want to retain previous element in a for loop. Suppose I have a following loop

```
for i in range(5):
     print i

0 
1
2
3
4
```

I want to retain `i=0` when `i=1(previous value)` in some variable. likewise `i=2` when `i=3` and so on. So,that I can use this previous value in a loop.

Comment: @vaultah That wouldn't be very flexible.  This is probably just an example.

Answer (score 4):

Put an initial value at the beginning, and then just reassign it at the end:

```
j = None
for i in range(5):
    print "j:", j
    print "i:", i
    j = i
    print
```

Output:

```
j: None
i: 0

j: 0
i: 1

j: 1
i: 2

j: 2
i: 3

j: 3
i: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(5):
     print i
     if i > 0: print 'previous:\t%d' %(i-1)
```

Comment: The word `suppose` was before `I have a following loop`.  This answer would work in *that* case, but not in a great many.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you are planning on using the previous value but Python's `itertools` module recipe `pairwise` may work for you:

```
from itertools import tee, chain

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

>>> for prev, curr in pairwise(range(5)):
...     print(prev ,curr)
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

And you need `curr` to include 0:

```
>>> for prev, curr in pairwise(chain([None],range(5))):
...     print(prev ,curr)
None 0
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```